# What is wrong with the this table creation sql?

Tags: mysql

```
/**
 * 検索条件保存テーブル作成
 */
 create table patient_search_conditions1 (
  id integer not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  office_id integer not null  COMMENT 'offices.id',
  save_name varchar(255)  null  COMMENT '検索条件',
  search_flag tinyint(3) default '1' COMMENT '簡易検索と詳細検索を区別',
  deleted_at datetime default null,
  created_at datetime not null,
  updated_at datetime not null,
  search_conditions text CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT '検索条件',
  search_mode varchar(255) default null COMMENT '検索モード',
) ENGINE=InnoDB  default CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT '検索条件保存'
```

When I execute this sql , it reminds me that the line 14 has error. where is wrong?

Comment: Which is at 14 line? What is the error?

Comment: Remove comma in this line `search_mode varchar(255) default null COMMENT '検索モード',`

Answer (score 1):

The sql query leads an error #1064 -

Remove a comma in this line

```
search_mode varchar(255) default null COMMENT '検索モード',
```